# Accurately finding the gradient of values from 2 vectors

Tags: julia, interpolation, automatic-differentiation

So I have a vector of x-coordinates and a vector of y-coordinates and I need the second derivative at each x. There is no function tht I can write the y coordinates as therefore I don't think I can use forwarddiff.jl, finitdifferences.jl etc.

Thank you so much,

Henry

I have tried both BSplinekit.jl and Inteprolations.jl but this is linked to a long coupled ODE equation therefore the errors in the ends or centre of these methods seem to accumulate and after 1000 iterations lead to very eroneous results. Is there a possibilty that I could somehow use one of the function methods such as forwarddiff by having a package generate an 'exact' function from my results. If you need any data, please ask.

My result from Interpolations.jl after 2370-ish cycles (should be a straight line on 100) right now

[image]

My result from BSplineKit.jl after 1000-ish cycles

[image]

The code that I am using is as follows:

```
function Heatconductivity(κrt,Tel,Tph,zgrid)
    S=Interpolations.interpolate(zgrid,Tel,Gridded(Linear()))
    dS=only.(gradient.(Ref(S),zgrid))
    Q=dS.*kappa_linear(κrt,Tel,Tph)
    Qint=Interpolations.interpolate(zgrid,Q,Gridded(Linear()))
    dQ=only.(gradient.(Ref(Qint),zgrid))
    dQ=dQ.*-1
end
```

Where Tel is a vector of temperatures at depths into a material given by zgrid. I need the second derivative of the change in temperature with respect to position which currently I am getting from Interpolations.jl. I have tried multiple alogrithms for the interpolation but not seem to yield much improved results.

The output then is fed as part of a ODE that updates the temperature at each time step so I can't write an algebraic expression for dTel/dz.

Comment: The charts are nice, but code is better. A minimum example with desired input and output is very good to get a question going.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have added the code and an explanation now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most accurate solution, but it may offer a quick stop-gap:

```
function d2f(x,y)
    h = diff(x)
    d2 = @. (2*(y[3:end] + h[2:end]/h[1:end-1]*y[1:end-2] - (1+h[2:end]/h[1:end-1])*y[2:end-1])/(h[2:end]*h[1:end-1]*(1+h[2:end]/h[1:end-1])))
    return d2
end
```

It is based on this old-ish paper: *A simple finite-difference grid with non-constant
intervals /
Hilding Sundqvist & George Veronis (1970)*.

The returned vector is the second derivatives at points of `x` except for the endpoints (i.e. `x[1]` and `x[end]`).

It isn't a full interpolation method, but perhaps it is enough for your use-case.

Testing:

```
julia> x = [1.0:0.1:2.0...];

julia> y = x.^2;

julia> d2f(x,y)
9-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.000000000000005
 2.000000000000001
 2.000000000000005
 2.000000000000001
 2.0000000000000426
 1.9999999999999605
 2.0000000000000453
 1.9999999999999605
 1.9999999999999563
```

Indeed the second derivative of `x^2` is `2`.